# Framework7 Route Protection

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

```
import HomePage from './pages/home.vue';
import Home2Page from './pages/home2.vue';
import NotFoundPage from './pages/not-found.vue';

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: HomePage,
    // check if the user is logged in
    beforeEnter: checkAuth,
  },
  {
    path: '/home2',
    component: Home2Page,
  },
  {
    path: '(.*)',
    component: NotFoundPage
  }
];


function checkAuth(to, from, resolve, reject) {
  if (true) {
    resolve({
      component: Home2Page
    });
  } else {
    reject();
  }
}
```

why is this checkAuth function not working? I try to check if the Page requires Auth, when it requires the function checkAuth should fire up. If the Auth is true in this case, the other Page should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `redirect` property instead of `beforeEnter`.

Example ([retrieved from the docs](http://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#redirect)) :

```
redirect: function (route, resolve, reject) {
  if (true) {
    resolve('myUrl');
  }
  else reject();
}
```

Comment: But when you look a little bit above by Route Before Enter/Leave, it should also work like i do it.

Comment: Ok i didn't see it. Can you check if that code work anyway ? 
Your error can be related to the warning at the end of [route api](http://framework7.io/vue/navigation-router.html#router-api) ?